# Wordpress Ninija form redirect

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I tried to redirect to another form/page by condition.
I used Ninja Forms (3.3.*) at Wordpress 4.9.*.
I created webhook.

following is code

```
add_action( 'generate_token', 'generate_token_callback' );
/**
 * @param $form_data array
 * @return void
 */
function generate_token_callback( $form_data ){
    global $ninja_forms_processing;

    $form_id       = $form_data[ 'form_id' ];
    $form_fields   =  $form_data[ 'fields' ];
    foreach( $form_fields as $field ){
        $field_id    = $field[ 'id' ];
        $field_key   = $field[ 'key' ];
        $field_value = $field[ 'value' ];

        // Example Field Key comparison
        if( 'my_field' == $field[ 'key' ] ){
            // This is the field that you are looking for.
        }
    }

    error_log( "get token - " . $form_id, 0 );

    $form_settings = $form_data[ 'settings' ];
    $form_title    = $form_data[ 'settings' ][ 'title' ];

    error_log( "get token 2 - " . $form_id, 0 );

    if($form_id == 2) {
        $url = get_home_url() . "/thankyou" ;
        wp_redirect( $url );
    }else{
        $url = get_home_url() . "/error" ;
        wp_redirect( $url );
    }

}
```

The wp_redirect is not working. How can I?

Updated ---

after adding the "exit();"

[image]

but not redirect to thankyou page.

Updated ---

done by

https://www.inkthemes.com/how-you-can-easily-create-customized-form-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You only miss the `exit()`. So just add it after `wp_redirect`. whenever use wp_redirect use `exit()` method.

```
 if($form_id == 2) {
    $url = get_home_url() . "/thankyou" ;
    wp_redirect( $url );
    exit(); // always exit
}else{
    $url = get_home_url() . "/error" ;
    wp_redirect( $url );
    exit(); // always exit
}
```

Comment: return 200 in inspect element but did not redirect to another page. I updated my question with screen.